# ReactNative navigation issue

Tags: react-native

I am working on a ReactNative app. The project is created using expo. I want to navigate to another component on button click. I am getting the following error while bundling

```
Unable to resolve "react-native-gesture-handler" from "node_modules\@react-navigation\native\src\Scrollables.js"
```

I did not find any solution on google and i am stuck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manged to resolve my issue by running

```
npm i -s react-native-gesture-handler
```